# How do I configure base_uri for my http request in symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

I am using symfony's HttpClientInterface to make a request to an API.

I know that my base uri will never change and I would like to configure it in /config/packages/framework.yml

Yet whenever I try to set the base_uri, symfony tells me that it is not an available option for http_client.

So, I have reasoned that it most likely must be an option of "scoped_clients" yet whenever I try the code below, Symfony tells me I am missing a base_uri and host or scheme.

```
    http_client:
        max_host_connections: 10
        scoped_clients:
            base_uri: '%app.api.coolapp.base_uri%'
        default_options:
            headers: { 'X-Powered-By': 'my App' }
            max_redirects: 7
```

So, I think I am missing the concept of the scoped client, because obviously it needs more information or something to get my request url correct. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats correct behaviour. Symfony needs a named client for that:

```
http_client
    scoped_clients:
        your_api.client: # <-- your configuration's missing this line
           base_uri: '%app.api.coolapp.base_uri%'

    # ...
```